# How to upgrade to xDebug to 2.3

Tags: php, macos, xdebug

I've installed the latest version of PHP (the 5.6.11 in this moment) using the package provided by [Liip](http://php-osx.liip.ch/).

There, there is xDebug 2.5.5.

How can I upgrade to xDebug 2.3.*?

Answer (score 2):

It was really simple:

```
$ sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Verify with:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.11 (cli) (built: Jul 10 2015 22:36:04) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```